# What's the difference between a Logical AND operator and a nested if statement?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I thought there would be none yet for some reason my program doesn't work when I use a Logical AND instead of a nested if statement. I made a Tetris clone that has a hold feature which holds/stores a block when the player presses the C key. I had a boolean that prevents the player from uncontrollably swapping blocks.

For some reason this works:

```
if (bKey[5]) //When C key is pressed
        {
            if (!pieceHold) //boolean to prevent player from holding the C key and swapping blocks constantly/uncontrollably
            {
                if (!bPieceHeld) //check to see if player is not holding a block
                {
                    r++;
                    nHoldPiece = nCurrentPiece; //set empty hold piece into the current piece
                    nHoldRotation = nCurrentRotation; 
                    nCurrentPiece = nNextPiece; //set the current piece into the next piece
                    
                    nNextPiece = rng[r - 1];
                    nCurrentX = nFieldWidth / 2;
                    nCurrentY = 0;
                    bPieceHeld = 1;
                }
                else if (bPieceHeld) //if player is already holding block, swap held block with the current block
                {
                    int tempPiece = nCurrentPiece;
                    nCurrentPiece = nHoldPiece;
                    nHoldPiece = tempPiece;

                    int tempRotation = nCurrentRotation;
                    nCurrentRotation = nHoldRotation;
                    nHoldRotation = tempRotation;
                }
            }
            pieceHold = 1; //set boolean to true if C is already held to prevent accidental double swapping
        }
else
            pieceHold = 0; //set boolean false if C key is held
```

But this doesn't:

```
if (!pieceHold && bKey[5])
    {
        if (!bPieceHeld)
        {
                r++;
                nHoldPiece = nCurrentPiece;
                nHoldRotation = nCurrentRotation;
                nCurrentPiece = nNextPiece;
                
                nNextPiece = rng[r - 1];
                nCurrentX = nFieldWidth / 2;
                nCurrentY = 0;
                bPieceHeld = 1;
        }
        else if (bPieceHeld)
        {
                int tempPiece = nCurrentPiece;
                nCurrentPiece = nHoldPiece;
                nHoldPiece = tempPiece;

                int tempRotation = nCurrentRotation;
                nCurrentRotation = nHoldRotation;
                nHoldRotation = tempRotation;
        }
        pieceHold = 1;
    }
    else
        pieceHold = 0;
```

The player can still swap the blocks uncontrollably despite the bool pieceHold being there to supposedly prevent that. Why is that?

Comment: The control flows are completely different. Best advice I can give you is to start your program in the debugger, step through line by line, and watch variables changing. Also always post a [mvce] here please, that reproduces the behavior you claim.

Comment: πάνταῥεῖ's trying to point you at [mre], but got typo-ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer if statement in the first code snippet contains an else part

```
if (bKey[5]) 
        {
            //...
            pieceHold = 1; //set boolean to true if C is already held to prevent accidental double swapping
        }
else
            pieceHold = 0; //set boolean false if C key is held
```

So

```
 if (bKey[5]) 
 //...
 else
 //..
```

is not the same as

```
if (!pieceHold && bKey[5])
//...
else
//...
```

Pay attention to that this if-else statements

```
            if (!bPieceHeld) //check to see if player is not holding a block
            //..
            else if (bPieceHeld)
```

can be rewritten simpler like

```
            if (!bPieceHeld) //check to see if player is not holding a block
            //..
            else
```

Also instead of manually swapping integers like

```
            int tempPiece = nCurrentPiece;
            nCurrentPiece = nHoldPiece;
            nHoldPiece = tempPiece;

            int tempRotation = nCurrentRotation;
            nCurrentRotation = nHoldRotation;
            nHoldRotation = tempRotation;
```

you could write

```
           std::swap( nCurrentPiece, nHoldPiece );
           std::swap( nCurrentRotation, nHoldRotation );
```

that makes your code more clear and readable.

Comment: How do I get the !pieceHold to have the else part? I tried swapping the 2 && operands before but nothing changed.

Comment: @NotApollo I have not understood whta you have written. I pointed out how if and else if can be substituted for if-else.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see the 2nd half of your comment.

Answer (score 7):

This nested if:

```
if (bKey[5]) 
{
   if (!pieceHold) 
   {
      // ...
   }
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (bKey[5] && !pieceHold)
```

In your example, you have swapped the conditions, which is not equivalent to the nested if.

Note that the condition is equivalent to the nested `if`, because `&&` will short-circuit. That means, that `!pieceHold` is only evaluated if `bKey[5]` is true.

Comment: Short-circuiting is the key here! May be a nice addition to add that into your (otherwise good) answer.

Comment: But the second statement doesn't do what the first one does. The player can still hold the C key and accidentally double swap.

Comment: "Short-circuiting", to clarify, that means that in `x && y` if `x` is false then `y` isn't even evaluated. For instance `print_a_return_false() && print_b_return_true()` would only print `a`.